# how to get azure webrole to log all 404s

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-roles

I have been trying to get logging working with azure for my MVC project but so far haven't had much success.

I have a Diagnostics connection string in my `ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg` file which points to my blob storage:

```
   ...
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConnectionString" value="**ConectionString**" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
```

My `web.config` has tracing set up

```
    ...
    <tracing>
      <traceFailedRequests>
        <remove path="*"/>
        <add path="*">
          <traceAreas>
            <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
            <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
            <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
            <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module" verbosity="Verbose" />
          </traceAreas>
          <failureDefinitions timeTaken="00:00:15" statusCodes="400-599" />
        </add>
      </traceFailedRequests>
    </tracing>
  </system.webServer>
```

My `WebRole.cs` has the following in

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;

namespace MvcWebRole1
{
    public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
    {
        public override bool OnStart()
        {
         // Get the factory configuration so that it can be edited
         DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration config = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();


         // Set scheduled transfer interval for infrastructure logs to 1 minute
         config.DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

         // Specify a logging level to filter records to transfer

         config.DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Verbose;

         // Set scheduled transfer interval for user's Windows Azure Logs to 1 minute
         config.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);


         DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConnectionString", config);

         //RoleEnvironment.Changing += this.RoleEnvironmentChanging;

         return base.OnStart();
        }
    }
}
```

But the I am not seeing any diagnostics logs

[image: Screenshot of Azure Blob Stoage]

The `mam` folder just contains an `MACommanda.xml` and a `MASecret`, `vsdeploy` folder is empty and the `wad-control-container` has a file for each deployment.

Am I missing something / doing something wrong?

I have been trying to follow the guides from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433048.aspx in particular http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Azure/Deployment/DeployingApplicationsinWindowsAzure/Exercise-3-Monitoring-Applications-in-Windows-Azure

**Update:**

I found the following which could be part of the problem

> IIS7 Logs Are Not Collected Properly -
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134842

although that should only account for the 404s not working, with a failure definition of 15 seconds my 17 second sleep in my controller action should have still been logged

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I was finally able to get all the logging working on the Azure web role:

In the WebRole.cs include the following:

```
 // Get the default initial configuration for DiagnosticMonitor.
        var config = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();

        // Filter the logs so that only error-level logs are transferred to persistent storage.
        config.DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = config.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = 
            config.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Verbose;

        // Schedule a transfer period of 30 minutes.
        config.DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = config.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = config.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferPeriod = 
            config.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod = config.PerformanceCounters.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

        // Specify a buffer quota.
        config.DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs.BufferQuotaInMB = config.Logs.BufferQuotaInMB = config.WindowsEventLog.BufferQuotaInMB = 
            config.Directories.BufferQuotaInMB = config.PerformanceCounters.BufferQuotaInMB = 512;

        // Set an overall quota of 8GB maximum size.
        config.OverallQuotaInMB = 8192;

        // WindowsEventLog data buffer being added to the configuration, which is defined to collect event data from the System and Application channel
        config.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("System!*");
        config.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("Application!*");

        // Use 30 seconds for the perf counter sample rate.
        TimeSpan perfSampleRate = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30D);

        config.PerformanceCounters.DataSources.Add(new PerformanceCounterConfiguration()
        {
            CounterSpecifier = @"\Memory\Available Bytes",
            SampleRate = perfSampleRate
        });

        config.PerformanceCounters.DataSources.Add(new PerformanceCounterConfiguration()
        {
            CounterSpecifier = @"\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time",
            SampleRate = perfSampleRate
        });

        config.PerformanceCounters.DataSources.Add(new PerformanceCounterConfiguration()
        {
            CounterSpecifier = @"\ASP.NET\Applications Running",
            SampleRate = perfSampleRate
        });



        // Start the DiagnosticMonitor using the diagnosticConfig and our connection string.
        DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString",config);


        return base.OnStart();
```

In the web.config under system.WebServer add the following:

```
    <tracing>
  <traceFailedRequests>
    <remove path="*"/>
    <add path="*">
      <traceAreas>
        <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module" verbosity="Verbose" />
      </traceAreas>
      <failureDefinitions statusCodes="400-599" />
    </add>
  </traceFailedRequests>
</tracing>
```

In the service definition file add the following under the web role:

```
 <LocalResources>
  <LocalStorage name="DiagnosticStore" sizeInMB="8192" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false"/>
</LocalResources>
```

That should enable all your logging in the MVC application.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by removing the "timeTaken" attribute from "failureDefinitions" node? Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965046(v=VS.90).aspx.

Comment: trying now, waiting for it to deploy. In on of my controller actions I had a sleep(17000) which should have triggered the timeTaken logging as per the channel9 guide but am not seeing the folders being created at all

Answer (score 0):

Check the deployment's diagnostics settings by viewing the appropriate file in wad-control-container.

I note that you are not setting what in my experience is all the required values for DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs or for Logs, including bufferQuotaInMB and scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter.

Try this:

```
             // Get the factory configuration so that it can be edited
         DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration config = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();

         config.DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs.bufferQuotaInMB = 512;
         config.DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1D);
         config.DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Verbose;

         config.Logs.bufferQuotaInMB = 512;
         config.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Verbose;
         config.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1D);
```

Try that to start.  Ensure as well that you have added trace listeners.